# Hive query to add extra character

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Can anyone help me to get this output with Hive query?

```
Input          output
00004500       45.00
00003400       34.00
23446700       234467.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  input / 100  as output
from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+-----------+
|  output   |
+-----------+
| 45.0      |
| 34.0      |
| 234467.0  |
+-----------+
```